# How to Split a Delimited Text file in Linux, based on no of records, which has end-of-record separator in data fields

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

Problem Statement:

I have a delimited text file offloaded from Teradata which happens to have "\n" (newline characters or EOL markers) inside data fields.

The same EOL marker is at the end of each new line for one entire line or record.

I need to split this file in two or more files (based on no of records given by me) while retaining the newline chars in data fields but against the line breaks at the end of each lines.

Example:

```
1|Alan
Wake|15
2|Nathan
Drake|10
3|Gordon
Freeman|11
```

Expectation :

*file1.txt*

```
1|Alan
Wake|15
2|Nathan
Drake|10
```

---

*file2.txt*

```
3|Gordon
Freeman|11
```

What i have tried :

```
 awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n"}NR%2==1{x="SplitF"++i;}{print > x}' inputfile.txt
```

The code can't discern between data field newlines and actual newlines. Is there a way it can be achieved?

EDIT:: i have changed the problem statement with example. Please share your thoughts on the new example.

Comment: elaborate this `based on no of records given by me`

Comment: watch this part "NR%2==..." means every two records i split

Comment: You're going to have to tell us what the criteria is for putting X lines in one file and Y in the other. There's a LOT of alternatives that could produce that output (split every 4 lines, split roughly in half while preserving pairs of lines, etc.) - tell us which one you actually want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using GNU awk you can do this by setting `RS` appropriately, e.g.:

*parse.awk*

```awk
BEGIN { RS="[0-9]\\|" }

# Skip the empty first record by checking NF (Note: this will also skip
# any empty records later in the input)
NF {
  # Send record with the appropriate key to a numbered file
  printf("%s", d $0) > "file" i ".txt"
}

# When we found enough records, close current file and 
# prepare i for opening the next one
#
# Note: NR-1 because of the empty first record
(NR-1)%n == 0 { 
  close("file" i ".txt")
  i++
}

# Remember the record key in d, again, 
# becuase of the empty first record
{ d=RT }
```

Run it like this:

```sh
gawk -f parse.awk n=2 infile
```

Where `n` is the number of records to put into each file.

Output:

*file1.txt*

```
1|Alan
Wake|15
2|Nathan
Drake|10
```

*file2.txt*

```
3|Gordon
Freeman|11
```

Comment: sorry it did not help :( I believe my explanation fell short to describe what i actually expect. I have changed the problem statement accordingly with a new example.

Comment: What's the RT in the last line meant to be?

Comment: Cheers @EdMorton. I really need to start reading changelogs. Missed that completely =}

Comment: @Thor... "mighty" thanks! worked like charm! you are the man!

Answer (score 2):

Use the following ***awk*** approach:

```
awk '{ r=(r!="")?r RS $0 : $0; if(NR%4==0){ print r > "file"++i".txt"; r="" } }
       END{ if(r) print r > "file"++i".txt" }' inputfile.txt
```

- `NR%4==0` - your *logical* single line occupies two *physical* records, so we expect to separate on each 4 records

---

*Results*:

```
> cat file1.txt 
1|Alan
Wake
2|Nathan
Drake
```

---

```
> cat file2.txt 
3|Gordon
Freeman
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but let me get this clear, "if(NR%4==0)" in this expression does the no "4" comes from the logic : "number of fields in a record X number of split" ? because here there are two column for each record, and i wanted two split files...so effectively modulus will be applied with "4" ?

Comment: in that case, what will happen to this file if i want to split it in 3 and each record has 3 fields each. the awk splits it the wrong way because of modulo 9

1|Alan"\n"
Wake|15"\n"
2|Nathan"\n"
Drake|10"\n"
3|Gordon"\n"
Freeman|11"\n"
4|Suman"\n"
Gupta|33"\n"
5|Indranil"\n"
Roy|34"\n"



with 

awk '{ r=(r!="")?r RS $0 : $0; if(NR%9==0){ print r > "file"++i".txt"; r="" } }
       END{ if(r) print r > "file"++i".txt" }' SplilineIN2.csv

Comment: @SumanGupta, you wrote *each record has 3 fields* - if we talk about fields then there should field separator. What is field in your case?

Comment: its "|" in this case, i have modified the example in my OP

Comment: @SumanGupta, extend your question with your new input and post the final expected output (in formatted view)

Comment: I actually changed the example set based on my expectation. Its formatted.

Comment: @SumanGupta, but my current approach returns the expected rows for your current input. What is the issue?