# Split large file into smaller files with certain number of records (awk, unix)

Tags: unix, awk, split

I'm trying to split a large file (>30,000 records) into multiple files each containing <= 4000 records.

I think awk might be the way to go on this.

Example file:

```
proteins.txt
    >gi|1000108|gb|AAA92500| melatonin receptor [Xenopus laevis]
    hsswynrlfsnsgticyvglvwvlalgailpnlfvgslrcdprifsctfaqyvssyytiavvifhfflpigvvsycylriwvlvlnirhrvkpdrhlhhqtwpynihgfitmfvvfvlfavcwgplniigltvaiypplgdsipqwlfvasyf
    >gi|1000110|gb|AAA92501| melatonin receptor [Xenopus laevis]
    hsfvyeklfslwntilyvcliwtltvvatvpnffvgsleydpriysctfvqtvsssytitvvvihfilpitvvtfcylriwilviqvrrkvksefkprmkqsdfrnfltmfvvfvifafcwaplnfiglavsinptevapkipewlfvvsyf
    >gi|1000406|gb|AAB34773| xCRABP=cellular retinoic acid binding protein [Xenopus laevis, stage 22/24 embryos, Peptide, 147 aa]
    mpnfsghwkmkqsenfeemlkalgvnlmlrkiavaaaskpaveikqegetfyiktsttvrtteinfklgggfdeqtvdgrncrslpewenenkihctqtvlegegpktswtrelandealiltmtaddvvctriyvrelnfwitpsl
```

Each record is seprated by ">"

so a single record is:

```
>gi|1000108|gb|AAA92500| melatonin receptor [Xenopus laevis]     
hsswynrlfsnsgticyvglvwvlalgailpnlfvgslrcdprifsctfaqyvssyytiavvifhfflpigvvsycylriwvlvlnirhrvkpdrhlhhqtwpynihgfitmfvvfvlfavcwgplniigltvaiypplgdsipqwlfvasyf
```

I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
awk -F, 'RS=">", {x=(NR<4000); print x}' proteins.txt > proteins4000.txt
awk -F, 'RS=">", {x=(NR>=4000 & NR <8000); print x}' proteins.txt > proteins8000.txt
...
```

but everything prints with this command...

Comment: 1600+ QA when you search for `[awk] split files`. Certainly this Q has been answered mutilple times. Good luck.

Comment: not splitting by record number... plenty on splitting by number of lines. My records are multiline.  Will continue to look tho.

Comment: why don't you do `head -10 myProblematicDataFile | awk '-v RS=">" {print NR "\t" $0}'` you should get your first 10 records. You already seem to know how to use `RS`. BUT I would really recommend either going back to your source data and configure it properly to output 1 line of data per record OR use a `sed` script to pre-join each 2 line part into a single record, and then process to split. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice and searched more thru stackoverflow results directly rather than by google.  Came up with an answer posted above.

Comment: Is each record always 2 lines?

Comment: No, always variable (can be 2-100+ lines)

Answer (score 1):

You can just do math with FNR, something like:

```
awk  'BEGIN{RS="\n[ \t]*>"; bl=4000}
                    FNR==1{sub(/^[ \t]*>/,"")}
                    {printf ">%s\n", $0 > "file" int(FNR / bl) }
                    ' file
```

That will break the file into blocks of `bl` length records in `file0 file1 file2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Answer, based on this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586923/how-to-split-a-delimited-text-file-in-linux-based-on-no-of-records-which-has-e)... there may be some elements that I don't really need though.

Create program `parse.awk`

```
BEGIN { RS=">" } NF {printf("%s", d $0) > "file" i ".txt"}(NR)%n == 0 {close("file" i ".txt") i++} {d = RT}
```

Then run:

```
gawk -f parse.awk n=4000 proteins.txt
```