# Splitting a large file with awk into chunks with a defined number of multi line records

Tags: bash, awk

I want to chunk a large file (>15G, several millions of records) into smaller chunks with a defined number of records. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Here are the rules:

1. For portability issue, I would like to stick to UNIX commands.
2. There is a specific pattern defining the end of each record ('$$$$') in the input file.
3. This pattern should be conserved to separate records in chunks
4. Each chunk should contain n records
5. Each record can vary in both number of lines.

I searched for similar questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51813099/split-large-file-into-smaller-files-with-certain-number-of-records-awk-unix), but could not find exactly what I was looking for.

Here is an example of the input file syntax.

example.sdf

```
Item1
  Mrv171c009131823372D          

  2  1  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
   -3.7946    2.9241    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.9708    2.9673    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <property_1>
3

$$$$
Element2
  Mrv171c009131823372D          

  2  1  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
   -3.6161    1.7634    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.7956    1.8496    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <property_1>
5

$$$$
Something3
  Mrv171c009131823372D          

  2  1  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
   -3.0580    0.5134    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.5772    1.1545    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <property_1>
10

$$$$
```

Desired output for n=2:

example.sdf.chunk000001

```
Item1
  Mrv171c009131823372D          

  2  1  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
   -3.7946    2.9241    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.9708    2.9673    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <property_1>
3

$$$$
Element2
  Mrv171c009131823372D          

  2  1  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
   -3.6161    1.7634    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.7956    1.8496    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <property_1>
5

$$$$
```

example.sdf.chunk000002

```
Something3
  Mrv171c009131823372D          

  2  1  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
   -3.0580    0.5134    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.5772    1.1545    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <property_1>
10

$$$$
```

At the moment, I tried to achieve this with split and awk (see below), but this looks clumsy. I also tried to have a look at csplit, but I could not find any option to set a defined number of records in each chunk.

#### split

split command works perfectly fine, but does not accept the '$$$$' delimiter as it is more than one character. I can get it work by replacing this pattern with a single character (@), but things could go wrong in case this other character is found in the SDF file.

```
# replace the separator with a dummy
sed -e 's/\$\$\$\$/@/g' export.sdf > example.sdf.tmp
# split the file (3 records) into smaller chunks (xaa, xab, ect.) with max 2 records
split -t @ -l 2 example.sdf.tmp
# replace the dummy with the proper separator
for f in xa*; do tail -n +2 $f |sed 's/@/\$\$\$\$/g' > $f.fixed; done
```

Unfortunately, this does not look very optimized to edit the input file and then every chunk, so I tried to use awk instead.

#### awk

I'm very new to awk, but I managed to get this:

```
awk 'NR%2==1 {x=sprintf(".chunk%06d",++i);} END {printf "%s",$0} {print>FILENAME x}' RS="\\$\\$\\$\\$" ORS="\$\$\$\$" example.sdf
```

The first chunk looks exactly what I am looking for but the second has two errors:

example.sdf.chunk000002

```
[ blank line ]     
Something3
  Mrv171c009131823372D          

  2  1  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
   -3.0580    0.5134    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.5772    1.1545    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <property_1>
10

$$$$
$$$$
```

As you can see, there is an empty line (which I could not display so I typed [blank line] instead) at the beginning of the file and one final end pattern at the end of the last chunk. I also tried on a file with 9 records, I got the empty line at the beginning of chunks 2-5 and the final extra '$$$$' at the end of chunk 5).

How could I fix this behavior so I get the expected output?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Jose Manuel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS, RT and handling of multiple open files:

```
$ awk -v RS='\n[$]{4}\n' 'NR%2{out="out"++c} {print $0 RT " > " out}' file
Item1
  Mrv171c009131823372D

  2  1  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
   -3.7946    2.9241    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.9708    2.9673    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <property_1>
3

$$$$
 > out1
Element2
  Mrv171c009131823372D

  2  1  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
   -3.6161    1.7634    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -2.7956    1.8496    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <property_1>
5

$$$$
 > out1
Something3
  Mrv171c009131823372D

  2  1  0  0  0  0            999 V2000
   -3.0580    0.5134    0.0000 N   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -3.5772    1.1545    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
> <property_1>
10

$$$$
 > out2
```

Just change `" > "` to `>` after you've tested and are happy with the output.

With any awk:

```
awk '
    NR==1 { out="out"++c }
    { print > out }
    ($0=="$$$$") && (((++nr)%2)==0) { close(out); out="out"++c }
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
awk 'BEGIN{n_records=2; counter=0};{print > "file_" int(counter/n_records) ".txt"; if($0 ~ /\$\$\$\$/){counter++}}' example.sdf
```

Comment: Be aware that this could become problematic on large files if you have _a lot of chunks_. It is advisable to `close` the previous file before moving to a new file.

Comment: Basically, it will only work in GNU awk. With all other awks it'll fail when you get past about 20 output files and with some it'll fail with a syntax error due to the output file expression not being parenthesized. Since it requires GNU you should have used multi-char `RS="$$$$"` instead of this approach. So, it's not a good aolution.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='\\$\\$\\$\\$\n' -v nb=2 -v c=1 '
{
   file=sprintf("%s%s%06d",FILENAME,".chunk",c)
   printf "%s%s",$0,RT > file 
}
NR%nb==0 {c++}
' example.sdk
```

The record separator `RS` to the pattern `$$$$` allows to get the full chunk at once.

The variable `nb` holds the number of chunk per file, and `c` is the counting number for the filename.

Comment: This removes the '$$$$' patten in the output files, but I need those.
I tried to fix this by specifying ORS='\\$\\$\\$\\$\n' but I got no difference in the output.

Comment: I can have what I wish by editing the printf :
   printf "%s%s$$$$\n",$0,RT > file

Comment: @JoseManuel The pattern `$$$$` is part of the output files as this is catch with `RT` variable. Maybe you're not using Gnu awk.

Comment: @JoseManuel Use `RS` instead of `RT` in the `printf` statement

Comment: you are correct, it looks like mawk is used by default in Ubuntu 16.04.
I tried to replace RS instead of RT, but get \$\$\$\$ instead in the chunks. Of course, if I switch RS='\\$\\$\\$\\$\n' to RS='$$$$\n', I don't get any chunks anymore.
It works if I define ORS='$$$$\n' and use printf ORS instead of RT in the printf statement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small update to the solution of [Cortenin Limier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52328139/8344060)

**original:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{n_records=2; counter=0}
    { print > "file_" int(counter/n_records) ".txt";
      if($0 ~ /\$\$\$\$/){counter++}}' example.sdf
```

**update:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{n_records=2; }
     (NR==1){ file=sprintf(FILENAME ".chunk%0.6d",counter) }
     { print > file }
     ($0=="$$$$"){ 
         close(file); 
         file=sprintf(FILENAME ".chunk%0.6d",(++counter/n_records))
     }' example.sdf
```

The differences are:

- any variable is by default ZERO or an empty string, so no need to define `counter=0`
- variable `file` holds the filename, so it is not generated at each step
- the `file` is closed when it is not needed anymore.
- We check if the record separator is actually at the beginning and end of the line.
- The output files will have the form `FILENAME.chunknnnnnn` where `FILENAME` is substituted by the original file called here `example.sdf`

Comment: The first record labelled "Row0" is missing from the first output example.sdf.chunk000000